# Rails 4 path traversal possible?

Tags: security, ruby-on-rails-4

The app I'm working on has a controller that issues templates to the front end (single page app). It's very basic, and simply consists of

```
@path = params[:path]
render template: "templates/#{@path}", layout: nil
```

Here my concern however is the direct use of the users input. Everything about this to me feels like it can be attacked with something as simple as path traversal. The route for this is

```
get "/templates/:path.html" => "templates#file", constraints: { path: /.+/ }, defaults: { format: 'html' }
```

I've tried multiple things to attempt a path traversal attack, such as

- request /templates/path/to/../somewhere/else.html
- request /templates?path=/path/to/../../something.rb
- request /templates/index.html?path=/path/to/../../config/something.html
- request /templates/path/../../../file.html

Fortunately, I haven't had any success with this. The requests that just start with `/templates` and don't specify anything after it, don't match the route thanks to the constraint so that is good.

It seems as though when that route is matched, rails doesn't allow you to override the `path` parameter through a url parameter, so I don't seem to be able to inject it there.

The ones that interest are the first and last examples above, where rails seems to internally be changing the requested URL before invoking the routes file. When I request `/templates/path/to/../somewhere/else.html`, my console output shows a request for `/templates/path/somewhere/else.html`. When I make a request for `/templates/path/../../../file.html`, the log shows a request for `/file.html`.

Am I missing something somewhere that will leave the app open to security issues, or is this just rails being sensible and protecting itself for me?

**UPDATE**

I've done some more digging, and if I try doing some URL encoding then I can cause the server to simply not respond at all. If I request `/templates/%2e%2e%2f%2e%2e%2f%2e%2e%2ffresult.html` then I just get an empty response with a `connection: close` header.

I assume that the parameter parser higher up in the rack is checking all urls for this type of attack? Regardless, my original question still stands. Am I missing something here?